# Multi ItemsSource (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
List<string> list = new List<string>();
  while (combodata.Read())
  {
     list.Add(combodata.GetString(0));
  }
source.DataSource = dt;

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = source;
```

how add `list` to `source`?

```
source.DataSource = dt;
source.DataSource = list;
```

wrong...

i need add `dataGrid1.ItemsSource` a `dt` and `list`
how i can?

Comment: what is the type of `source`?

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource source = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx):

```
var cc = new CompositeCollection();
cc.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = new DataView(dt) });
cc.Add(new CollectionContainer { Collection = list });
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = cc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set `DataTable` as `ItemsSource` because it does not implement `IEnumerable`. You can use DataView:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... how do you add the list ?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? to join two collections? By the way, you can not use forms BindingSource in WPF. Does not make sence.

Comment: Look at @ThomasLevesque answer.